# Git development workflow

Tags: git, version-control

I am still a bit new on Version Control systems.

Currently I have two branches: `master` and `develop`. Yesterday I was working on the develop branch and came to realize that what I've made was wrong, so I had to switch back to some older commit.

The problem is that in recent commits I've added a couple of new unit-tests and improved considerably some key unit-testing infrastructure classes, that I'll want to keep in my project, even after coming back to an older commit.

This made me realize that maybe what I should have done since the beginning is having a branch related to all those features that are "project related" and not necessarily "current feature" related. Am I right?

How do you handle such things in your daily workflows w/ git?

Answer (score 5):

I would like to recommend the article [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) to you, it uses feature branches, develop branch, release branches, and hoxfixes to represent different purpose. And another Git extension you may have interest in is [gitflow](https://github.com/nvie/gitflow), it provides high-level repository operations for the branching model mentions in the article.

Comment: While that's an excellent article, I'm not sure that it's suitable for somebody who's new to version control systems. It's sort of like describing how to construct a house when the student is still learning the hammer and drill.

Comment: @Greg, I disagree.  People new to version control are "building a house" anyway.  Their software will have the same complexity, and they're still going to have the same changes they want to revert.  Having the right branching model can make those tasks much easier.  It's more like someone told them building a house was easier with these tools, but they can't figure out why they keep having to tear down and rebuild walls.  A good branching model is like a blueprint that avoids hard to fix mistakes in the first place, even though it may seem easier in the short term to just start hammering.

Answer (score 3):

In this specific case, I'd create a new branch (called ImproveUnitTests) from master then cherry-pick in the commits related to that topic that you've done from development.  Then your ImproveUnitTests can easily be merged back into master on its own.

For day-to-day stuff I use a LOT of branches.  If I'm developing featureX and see that I need to fix something else, I'll switch back to my master and make a new branch just to fix that stuff.  Then merge my "fixit" branch into master, and rebase featureX off that.

Answer (score 1):

If I get you right you want to revert your changes, but keep some of them. In that case I would switch to master and cherry pick the changes that was good (the unit test changes) and then just revert the develop branch and be happy :)